# Can't open Word doc with COM in PHP

Tags: php, com, ms-word

I'm trying to open and read the contents of a Word document with PHO by using the COM function. But whenever i try to read the contents, then it gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message
>   '**Source:** Microsoft Word
> **Description:** This command is
>   not available because no document is open.'

I have the following code:

```
    $word = new \COM ( "word.application" ) or die ( "Could not initialise MS Word object." );
    $word->Documents->Open ( realpath("test.doc" ) );

    // Extract content.
    $content = (string) $word->ActiveDocument->Content;

    echo $content;

    $word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);

    $word->Quit();
    $word = null;
    unset($word);
```

I'm 100% sure that the Word document exists. I've checked this numerous times. The permissions on the file are set to `Full Control`. So that can't be it either.

---

I've also read a comment on php.net. It said that IIS is causing a problem (i have that running). His solution was this:

- Execute "dcomcnfg"
- Open Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config
- Search for Microsoft Office Word 97-2003 Document (it will be something like this translated to your language, so take a while and search for it) **<-- Stuck at this one, can't find anything called "Microsoft Office..."**
- Right-Click on it and open the properties
- Choose "Identity" tab
- Normally this is set to "the launching user". You have to change this to "the interactive user" or a admin user of your choice.
- Apply these new settings and test your COM application. It should work fine now.

In anyway, i still haven't got this working. Anyone any idea how could possibly fix this error...???

Comment: I'm forced to use this computer with a normal user account, so PHP in IIS can never run COM (plus some other functionality), but PHP in CLI can. Haven't test this yet, but if I really have to use COM, I would make it a CLI script and let CGI script execute it in things like `exec`.

Comment: It seems that `word 2007` doesn't need this configuration? I cannot find this DCOM Config for my word 2007. But the COM runs very well. So anyone helps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found the solution. The steps i talked about:

- Execute "dcomcnfg"
- Open Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config
- Search for Microsoft Office Word 97-2003 Document (it will be s....
- etc..

That works. But like i said, i couldn't find the `Microsoft Office Word 97-2003` config. So  this is what i've done in order to make it appear in the list.

1. Start
2. Run
3. mmc -32
4. File
5. Add Remove Snap-in
6. Component Services
7. Add
8. OK
9. Console Root
10. Component Services
11. Computers
12. My Computer
13. DCOM Config
14. Microsoft Excel Application

So now you should be able to follow the steps from my first post. And PHP should then be able to read the docs without any trouble.

Comment: Works on my win10 computer. But it doesn't work on my win7 with word2007...

Comment: It seems that `word 2007` doesn't need this configuration? I cannot find this DCOM Config for my word 2007. But the COM runs very well. So anyone helps?